# Prevent Emacs switch-to-buffer-other-window From Resizing Other Window

Tags: emacs

I often have split windows in a frame where one is much smaller than the other (usually done through <kbd>C-u C-u C-x ^</kbd>). This is so I can see some snippet of code as reference while doing something else.

The problem is: when I use <kbd>C-x 4 b</kbd> to switch to some other buffer (or <kbd>C-x 4 f</kbd> to open a new file in the lower window), the lower window is resized to its original half-the-frame height size. Is there a way to stop that from happening and keep my smaller window size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you evaluate `(setq even-window-heights nil)` before running <kbd>C-x 4 f</kbd> (or a similar command), Emacs won't try to balance the heights of your windows.  Here's the documentation for `even-window-heights`:

> If non-nil **display-buffer** will try to even window heights.
>   Otherwise **display-buffer** will leave the window configuration
>   alone.  Heights are evened only when **display-buffer** chooses a
>   window that appears above or below the selected window.

I recommend writing a small elisp function that sets this variable to nil and then calls `switch-to-buffer-other-window` or `find-file-other-window`, since it's probably something that you'll want to do frequently.

Answer (score 0):

`C-x 4 b` isn't really a nav command. Do you still have the problem if you `C-x b` or simply `C-x o`?

Comment: It's the navigating that's the problem. C-x b and C-x o work fine. It's when I want to show another buffer (or open another file) in the lower window that things get resized. Edited the question to try to make that clearer.